# загрузка react проекта на хостинг

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hosting

после загрузки на хостинг react проект не отображается. какие могут быть причины?
как можно исправить?
[image: не отображается проект]
[image: console]

[image: видит только index.html]

сайт не видит папок. только index.html

Comment: Вы думаете, есть некий универсальный магический ответ? Нужны подробности.

Comment: да, нужны подробности. Как собирали приложение перед выгрузкой на хостинг?

Comment: @Maneken использовала npm run build и через filezilla добавила проект. но виден только index.html и все остальные папки он не видит..

Comment: скорее всего не все файлы перенеслись. проверь все, что загрузил, загрузилось ли. и посмотри что собралось в папке после буилд. у меня с npm run build не было такой проблемы.